# How to use Moonlight to play videos on rtlmost.hu?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, debug, moonlight

In Hungary, the biggest TV channel is **RTL Klub**, they has a video archive site. They use Silverlight instead of Flash :( What is annoying, they use the lastest version of Silverlight, about 4.x. But Moonlight doesn't support it yet.

I've been tried in Google Chrome (last dev version), and in Firefox (last stable version), and I've been used the both versions of Moonlight, the [lastest stable](http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/download.aspx), and the [prerelease](http://go-mono.com/moonlight/prerelease.aspx).

The player loader is displayed, and loaded, but no player displayed after 30 mins waiting.

**If I want to switch to Ubuntu completly, how can I manage to play these videos?**

Thanks for your anwsers.

Testvideo [here](http://www.rtlklub.hu/most/17345_hirado_lelki_terror_-_elrabloi_tobbszor_eljatszottak_hogy_ki). And [this is a working video](http://www.aquosgames.com/spectrum/spectrumfull.html) for me.

Also reported to moonlight developers, [here](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=664811).

Debug info:

```
Source: http://www.rtlklub.hu/most/player/soda/SodaMediaCenter.Player.Rtl.v3.5.xap
Width: 555px
Height: 490px
Background: #
RuntimeVersion: 4.0.50826.0
Windowless: no
MaxFrameRate: 60
Codecs: ms-codecs
Build configuration: debug, sanity checks
```

Prereleased Firefox output with WinCodecs installed:

```
$ firefox http://www.rtlklub.hu/most/17345_hirado_lelki_terror_-_elrabloi_tobbszor_eljatszottak_hogy_ki
Moonlight: 2.99.0.10
Moonlight: Attempting to load libmoonloaderxpi 
debug_get_option: GALLIUM_DRIVER = softpipe
couldn't open libtxc_dxtn.so, software DXTn compression/decompression unavailable
Moonlight: no audio capture service available
Moonlight: Installing signal handlers for crash reporting.
Moonlight: Enabling MONO_DEBUG=keep-delegates,reverse-pinvoke-exceptions and MOONLIGHT_ENABLE_CONSOLE=1
windowless mode
Using the ff3 bridge
Moonlight: Plugin AppDomain Creation: OK
Moonlight: Plugin AppDomain Creation: OK
Moonlight: URL = http://www.rtlklub.hu/most/17345_hirado_lelki_terror_-_elrabloi_tobbszor_eljatszottak_hogy_ki
Moonlight: URL = http://www.rtlklub.hu/most/player/soda/SodaMediaCenter.Player.Rtl.v3.5.xap
debug_get_bool_option: GALLIUM_NOSSE = FALSE
debug_get_bool_option: GALLIUM_DUMP_FS = FALSE
debug_get_bool_option: SOFTPIPE_DUMP_GS = FALSE
debug_get_bool_option: DRAW_FSE = FALSE
debug_get_bool_option: DRAW_NO_FSE = FALSE
debug_get_bool_option: GALLIUM_DUMP_VS = FALSE
debug_get_bool_option: SP_NO_RAST = FALSE
debug_get_bool_option: GALLIUM_NOSSE = FALSE
Using managed xaml parser.
Exception while parsing reader (19:26):
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Could not convert attribute value '0.375' on element GradientStop.
  at Mono.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseAttributeValue (Mono.Xaml.XamlObjectElement element, Mono.Xaml.XamlPropertySetter property) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseAttribute (Mono.Xaml.XamlObjectElement element) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseElementAttributes (Mono.Xaml.XamlObjectElement element) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseObjectElement () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseElement () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseReader (System.IO.TextReader stream) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Caught exception: Could not convert attribute value '0.375' on element GradientStop.
  at Mono.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseReader (System.IO.TextReader stream) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xaml.SL4XamlLoader.HydrateInternal (System.Object value, System.IO.Stream xaml, Boolean createNamescope, Boolean validateTemplates, Boolean import_default_xmlns) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xaml.XamlLoader.Hydrate (System.Object value, System.IO.Stream stream) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Xaml.XamlLoader:Hydrate (object,System.IO.Stream)
  at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent (System.Object component, System.Uri resourceLocator) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at SkyInteractive.Media.Web.Player.Rtl.MainPage.InitializeComponent () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at SkyInteractive.Media.Web.Player.Rtl.MainPage..ctor (IDictionary`2 initParams) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at SkyInteractive.Media.Web.Player.Rtl.App.Application_Startup (System.Object sender, System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Application.OnStartup (System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Deployment.CreateApplication () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Deployment.LoadAssemblies () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Deployment.InitializeDeployment (IntPtr plugin, System.String xapPath, System.String culture, System.String uiCulture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Moonlight: ErrorEventArgs created with message: 'Caught exception: Could not convert attribute value '0.375' on element GradientStop.'

(firefox-bin:11629): Moonlight-WARNING **: (plugin-class.cpp:609):static void Moonlight::EventListenerProxy::proxy_listener_to_javascript(Moonlight::EventObject*, Moonlight::EventArgs*, void*): runtime check failed: (js_sender != NULL)
not implemented: (ErrorEventArgs.lineNumber) plugin-class.cpp:842
not implemented: (ErrorEventArgs.methodName) plugin-class.cpp:855
windowless mode
Using the ff3 bridge
Moonlight: Plugin AppDomain Creation: OK
Moonlight: Plugin AppDomain Creation: OK
Shutting down
Moonlight: URL = http://www.rtlklub.hu/most/17345_hirado_lelki_terror_-_elrabloi_tobbszor_eljatszottak_hogy_ki
Moonlight: URL = http://www.rtlklub.hu/most/player/soda/SodaMediaCenter.Player.Rtl.v3.5.xap
debug_get_bool_option: GALLIUM_NOSSE = FALSE
debug_get_bool_option: GALLIUM_DUMP_FS = FALSE
debug_get_bool_option: SOFTPIPE_DUMP_GS = FALSE
debug_get_bool_option: SP_NO_RAST = FALSE
Using managed xaml parser.
Exception while parsing reader (19:26):
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Could not convert attribute value '0.375' on element GradientStop.
  at Mono.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseAttributeValue (Mono.Xaml.XamlObjectElement element, Mono.Xaml.XamlPropertySetter property) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseAttribute (Mono.Xaml.XamlObjectElement element) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseElementAttributes (Mono.Xaml.XamlObjectElement element) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseObjectElement () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseElement () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseReader (System.IO.TextReader stream) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Caught exception: Could not convert attribute value '0.375' on element GradientStop.
  at Mono.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseReader (System.IO.TextReader stream) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xaml.SL4XamlLoader.HydrateInternal (System.Object value, System.IO.Stream xaml, Boolean createNamescope, Boolean validateTemplates, Boolean import_default_xmlns) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Xaml.XamlLoader.Hydrate (System.Object value, System.IO.Stream stream) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Xaml.XamlLoader:Hydrate (object,System.IO.Stream)
  at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent (System.Object component, System.Uri resourceLocator) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at SkyInteractive.Media.Web.Player.Rtl.MainPage.InitializeComponent () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at SkyInteractive.Media.Web.Player.Rtl.MainPage..ctor (IDictionary`2 initParams) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at SkyInteractive.Media.Web.Player.Rtl.App.Application_Startup (System.Object sender, System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Application.OnStartup (System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Deployment.CreateApplication () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Deployment.LoadAssemblies () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Deployment.InitializeDeployment (IntPtr plugin, System.String xapPath, System.String culture, System.String uiCulture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Moonlight: ErrorEventArgs created with message: 'Caught exception: Could not convert attribute value '0.375' on element GradientStop.'

(firefox-bin:11629): Moonlight-WARNING **: (plugin-class.cpp:609):static void Moonlight::EventListenerProxy::proxy_listener_to_javascript(Moonlight::EventObject*, Moonlight::EventArgs*, void*): runtime check failed: (js_sender != NULL)
not implemented: (ErrorEventArgs.lineNumber) plugin-class.cpp:842
not implemented: (ErrorEventArgs.methodName) plugin-class.cpp:855
Shutting down
NOTE: child process received `Goodbye', closing down
```

Comment: I would really like to answer this question but the only solution I found involved using a windows program through wine (no guarantee that it will work) and you still need to start the video to start recording and silverlight in wine is a no go. Its not just a problem for Linux users Mac users will be affected too and I'm sure rtlnow.de users will have the same problem. Its possible that a solution may come from Germany as there are many Linux user's there who will no doubt have a similar problem.

Comment: Hmm, I think they use Flash, doesn't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although  simplistic answer this worked for me, I checked both of your links and they worked (with a rather slow video):

- I used Chrome 11.0.696.25 (79504) Ubuntu 10.10
- Installed Moonlight from here http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/download.aspx (installed 64bit)
- When I opened the video, it required me some Windows Codecs but Chromium downloaded some and at the end I close the  RTL Klub page and reopend it and it worked.

Comment: When I last tested, it was v2.99.0.10, but now, it is: v2.99.0.*2*, maybe they have fixed that :) - Thanks, now it works, but it slow :) - and that's not your(user's) problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a codec issue since the video isn't shown but player is loaded. Have you installed ubuntu-restricted-extras package?

Comment: It is installed right now... but same thing, loader & no video... :(

Comment: Have you added the mscodec pack from the right click menu they are only from moonlight. It didn't make any difference for me but I am only using stable moonlight might work with the development release plus start firefox with one tab open from the terminal to test for any output messages might give you a clue to any problems.

Comment: @Allan - Yes, Codecs already installed, I added the output...